# Split Conference Wordpress Page in different years

Tags: customization, pages, site-url

let's assume I have a page called conferencepage2018.page
This would be a bad way of doing it since the conference is being held every year. What am I supposed to do if I want to split the Wordpress page in years. For example conferencepage.page/2018 should contain everything happened in this year, also for 2019 and so on. The page must remain in the same design. What's the best way of achieving that structure, best way would be without installing new wp pages for every year.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be to use [WordPress Multisite](https://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network). This allows you to have multiple sites within one single installation (a so called network).

All sites can use the same theme/design and you can choose which users are allowed to edit content on which sites.

In case you're not sure if that really works, rest assured: this is how [WordCamp.org](https://central.wordcamp.org/) organizes all their conference websites under the hood. And they have lots of them.

There's also tons of documentation on the web about Multisite as it's really a proven way to organize sites.